# Why does this pde give Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent error? (1D heat pde)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have been staring at this simple pde for last 20 minutes and can't find why I am getting this error

```
Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent
```

it is that standard 1D heat equation

```
 eq = Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]
```

and boundary conditions are  (notice they are both spatial derivatives)

```
u'(0,t)=0     (derivative here w.r.t.  x )
u'(Pi,t)=0    (derivative here w.r.t.  x )
```

and initial conditions are

```
u(x,0) = cos(2 x)
```

So at initial condition, `u'(x,0) = -2 sin(2 x)`, which is zero at both `x=0` and `x=Pi`.

So it seems to me to be consistent with boundary conditions, right? or Am I missing something?

Here is the actual Mathematica code:

```
ClearAll[u, x, t]
eq = Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]

sol = NDSolve[{eq, 
               Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, 
               Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == 0, 
               u[x, 0] ==  Cos[2 x]}, 
               u, {t, 0, 12}, {x, 0, Pi}
              ]
```

I have a feeling since it is a numerical solver, using Pi in the above, become Real  Pi=3.1415... and so at exactly this value the initial and boundary conditions do not match? (floating point comparison somewhere?)

I know about the trick to resolve such an error from help `ref/message/NDSolve/ibcinc` but my question is really why I am getting this error in the first place, since it seems on the face of it, they are consistent. If it is due to the floating point issue with Pi, then how to resolve this? I tried to use the trick shown in help on this one (i.e. the use of exp(-1000 t) but did not help in removing this error.

**question: Why I am getting this error message ?**

version 8.04, on windows.

Actually I have been trying to get this solution shown here (also using Mathematica)

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Heatequation_exampleB.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aHeatequation_exampleB.gif)

but the BC and IC shown in the above example gave me this error also, so I made the change in the BC in the hope they become consistent now.

thanks.

**edit(1)**

Here are the commands I used to plot the plot the solution, and it looks ok

```
eq = Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]
sol = u /. 
  First@NDSolve[{eq, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, 
     Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == 0, u[x, 0] ==  Cos[2 x]}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1.5}, {x, 0, Pi}]
Animate[Plot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 1.5}]
```

**edit(3)**

I am still little confused (also did not have coffee yet, which does not help).

I changed the IC so that it is not derivative any more so that the IC (non-derivative) now agrees with the BC's (but those are kept as derivatives). But I still get the same error:

```
eq = Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]
sol = u /. 
  First@NDSolve[{eq, 
                 Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, 
                 Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == 0, 
                 u[x, 0] == Sin[2 x]}, 
                 u, {t, 0, 1.5}, {x, 0, Pi}
                ]

NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. >>
```

Also the solution appears ok when plotted

```
Animate[Plot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 1.5}]
```

What IC is needed for this problem to eliminate this erorr, or is it the case then that only essential BC must be used? and also non-derivative IC's be used, and only after that, I worry on the consistency part?

Comment: It does give a solution, and the solution is correct, despite the warning.  `Animate[Plot[u[x, t] /. First[sol], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, 1}]`  I agree that the warning is btoh confusing and worrying (what may be going wrong?)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did plot the solution and it looked OK, hence my question. Please see edit for the command to plot with animation. and thanks for confirming.

Comment: In your case the BCs are consistent with the derivative of the ICs, but the message is about the BCs not beeing consistent with the ICs. NDSolve does not integrate the ICs and BCs to find out if that is the case.

Comment: @ruebenko, I am sorry, I am not following only becuase I changed the IC to be `Sin[2x]`, which is now zero at `x=0` and also zero at `x=Pi` (notice the IC not its derivative now agrees with the BC, as you suggested I should do), and so it should be consistent with the BC, right? But NDSolve still gave me the same error. please see edit(2). So, what IC should I give in my example so that I do not get this error? I am not changing the BC, kept them as they are. Or are you saying that BC has to be essentials and not be derivatives as well? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to dig through it now, but I want to point out this [very detailed tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html) on numerical PDE solving, which has a full section dedicated to inconsistent boundary conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Szabolcs gave the right hint (See inconsistent boundary condition section in http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html)

```
eq = Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]
sol = u /. 
  First@NDSolve[{eq, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, 
     Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Cos[2 x]}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1.5}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 100}}]
```

I have filed a suggestion, that the link to the tutorial be added to the NDSolve::ibcinc message page.

Comment: Thanks to you and Szabolcs. I wrote a solver for this using crank nicolson method and wanted to use NDSolve to verify my solution. So this helps.

Comment: Here's another example of the same problem: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20729/12  (another argument to add that link to the message page).